# Replacing table with view, FKs getting in way

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints

I'm attempting to replace a table with a view of the same name. I can't drop the table because other tables reference it via FK constraints. I want to keep those FKs pointing to the view once it's created, so I don't really want to drop the FKs and then have to recreate them. Is there a way to reassure SqlServer that I'm going to restore its beloved integrity in just a sec? Or am I stuck with querying for all FKs referencing the table, disabling them, then re-enabling them once I've created the table-replacing view?

Comment: What would be the point of having a foreign key on a view? I'm not even sure how that would even work, if someone inserted data into an underlying table that didn't satisfy the FK constraint on the view would you expect the insert to be rejected?

Comment: *palm* you're right, of course - I need to change the FKs to point at the tables from which the view selects. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not allow you to drop a table where there is a view connected.

You need to first drop your view in order to drop the table. Then re-create the view.

So, its not just related to the foreign key, but more in how SQL-Server protects your database.